# Why does the definition of Contraction of Tensor assumes dot product values 1 or 0 only?

Tags: tensors

[image]

When the index of a Tensor is repeated $a_{\beta j}a_{\beta l} = \delta_{jl}$ is the dot product of columns j and l of rotation matrix A.

But This dot product can have only two values 1 or 0 and replaced by Kronecker Delta Function $\delta_{jl}$

Why this dot product is defined in this way so that in can have only 2 values viz. 1 or 0 and not in between?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that $a$ is a real operator representing a rotation about the origin in $\mathbb R^n$, and furthermore that the indices are with respect to some *orthonoral* basis $\vec e_i$ (index notation is also used in non-orthonormal bases, but in that case it is typical to distinguish between covariant and controvariant indices, which as far as I can tell isn't the case here). You might want to look through the the text and verify that this is indeed the case.

Rotations have a few useful properties, chief among which is that they are inner product preserving (often, this is used as the *definition* of a rotation):
$$\langle a\vec u,a\vec v\rangle = \langle\vec u,\vec v\rangle\ \ \ \forall \vec u,\vec v$$
Of course, the columns of $a$ are precisely the results of $a$ acting on the standard basis vectors $\vec e_i$, from which we see that if the basis vectors are orthonormal, so too are their images under $a$:
$$\langle a\vec e_j,a\vec e_l\rangle = \langle\vec e_j,\vec e_l\rangle=\delta_{jl}$$
In index notation, that is:
$$a_{\beta j}a_{\beta l} = \delta_{jl}$$

Comment: Thanks.. Means this delta notation can be used only for rotation in space with othonormal basis vectors, Right?

Comment: In a sense, yes. Really, the Kronecker delta is just the index notation for the identity operator. The fact that this operator induces the inner product is specific to orthonormal bases. In other settings, you may instead see the inner product written using the metric tensor $g$ e.g. $$\langle\vec u,\vec v\rangle=u^ig_{ij}v^j$$ This tensor won't generally be $\delta_{ij}$.